# Reason for mix of 해체 and 하십시오체 in the phrase 만나서 반갑습니다

Tags: grammar, word-choice, formal

Why is it 만나서 반갑습니다 and not 만나**니** 반갑습니다? The verb is clearly in 하십시오체, so shouldn't the 'Cause/Reason Connective Form' (as wiktionary calls it) 서 also be of the form 니?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true that -(으)니 is associated exclusively with 하십시오체, nor is -(아/어)서 associated exclusively with 해체. In fact, these causal connective forms are used pretty much across all speech levels, although there is a distinct poetic / old vibe to -(으)니.

This [blog post](http://koreanla.blogspot.com/2011/09/in-seung-ki-lees-song.html) gives a good summary of the uses for -(으)니. You can see that it is more related to -(으)니까 in its causal meaning. The [distinction](https://letusstudykorean.com/%EC%96%B4%EC%95%84%EC%97%AC%EC%84%9C-vs-%EC%9C%BC%EB%8B%88%EA%B9%8C-differences-and-important-rules/) [between](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Vr6QZvcOV8) [-(아/어)서 and -(으)니까](http://talktomeinkorean.libsyn.com/ttmik-level-5-lesson-14) I'm sure you're familiar with, as it is a fundamental piece of Korean grammar.

One of the links above [also states](http://talktomeinkorean.libsyn.com/ttmik-level-5-lesson-14) how only -(아/어)서 is used in "basic greetings". I perceive that because -(아/어)서 is for "naturally" arising cause-to-effect relationships, only that form is appropriate for 만나서 반갑습니다.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Michaelyus's nice answer, one more thing to consider is that 만나서 반갑습니다 is a fixed phrase.

Consider English "Good morning": you don't say "nice morning" even though *good* and *nice* are pretty much interchangeable, because it's a fixed phrase.  Same for 만나서 반갑습니다.

- Also, sentence-connecting(?) suffixes like -(으)니 aren't really associated with speech levels.  You can have a perfectly natural expression with -으니 at any speech level, e.g.,

> 해가 **지니** 추워/춥네/춥다/추워요/춥습니다/etc. = It's cold now that the sun went down.
>
> 그렇게 **하니** 망가지지(요)! = You are doing it like *that*, that's why it breaks!